# Error while running the exe file made with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-vlc

I tried to make a standalone executable of my python script with [auto-py-to-exe](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/) , it basically provides easy interface for creating executable with pyinstaller, so I made my python script's exe, it's console based and when I try to run the exe that I made of my script, then console opens up for a second a closes with bunch of errors quickly. However, the script runs fine in idle.
I had attached a screenshot of the error I received. As per my observations most probably the error is occurring due to the import of VLC module as in error trace you will see it occurred from line 2 and that line I had imported VLC. I have also observed by changing the line number of import for VLC.
I am quite a beginner, So I need to know the steps for the solution.
[image: error trace]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import vlc
import pafy
import urllib.request
import time


textToSearch = 'tremor dimitri vegas ' 
query = urllib.parse.quote(textToSearch)
urlq = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + query
response = urllib.request.urlopen(urlq)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
track_links=[]
i=0
for vid in soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'yt-uix-tile-link'}):
    i=i+1
    print('https://www.youtube.com' + vid['href'])
    track_links.append('https://www.youtube.com' + vid['href'])
    if i==2:
        break
print()


url = track_links[1]
video = pafy.new(url)
best = video.getbestaudio()
playurl = best.url
ins = vlc.Instance()
player = ins.media_player_new()

code = urllib.request.urlopen(url).getcode()
if str(code).startswith('2') or str(code).startswith('3'):
    print('Stream is working and playing song')
else:
    print('Stream is dead')

Media = ins.media_new(playurl)
Media.get_mrl()
player.set_media(Media)
player.play()

time.sleep(20)
player.stop()#breaking here just for check purpose
```

now here is the complete error trace

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line   149, in _
 _init__
 File "ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
 OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "liveyoutbe.py", line 2, in <module>
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in  _find_and_load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
 File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
 line 627, in exec_module
 exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
 File "site-packages\vlc.py", line 207, in <module>
 File "site-packages\vlc.py", line 163, in find_lib
 File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line  151, in _
_init__
 __main__.PyInstallerImportError: Failed to load dynlib/dll 'libvlc.dll'. Most pr
 obably this dynlib/dll was not found when the application was frozen.
 [6032] Failed to execute script liveyoutbe`
```

Comment: Please post your code and open the exe in cmd and put the traceback here as a text.

Comment: I have edited the quesion and added the code as well as the error trace, please help I am a beginner

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python VLC needs external dependencies like the DLL files you see in the error. So you need to add them to your executable output with [`add-data`](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/spec-files.html#adding-data-files).

Just copy all those `*.dll` inside your current VLC install path (e.g `C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC`) besides to your script and use below command to generate your executable:

```
pyinstaller.exe -F --add-data "./libvlc.dll;." --add-data "./axvlc.dll;." --add-data "./libvlccore.dll;." --add-data "./npvlc.dll;." script.py
```

Edit: It seems that you still need one more dependency which is `plugins` directory. Just add the whole plugins directory in your VLC path to your executable output. For that after executing above command you would get a spec file add `a.datas += Tree('<path_to_vlc_plugins_dir>', prefix='plugins')` to the file like this:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['script.py'],
             pathex=['<root_project_path>'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('./libvlc.dll', '.'), ('./axvlc.dll', '.'), ('./libvlccore.dll', '.'), ('./npvlc.dll', '.')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)

a.datas += Tree('<path_to_vlc_plugins_dir>', prefix='plugins')
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='script',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

Finally, execute this:

```
pyinstaller script.spec
```

Comment: hey , as you said i tried to add all required file and made exe . but when i ran the executable it run for a while ( executing the half part of program) and ended again with error `C:\Users\intel\Desktop>liveyoutbe.exe
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9vMh9f41pqE
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVrB_vfS3AQ

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "liveyoutbe.py", line 34, in <module>
    player = ins.media_player_new()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'media_player_new'
[5172] Failed to execute script liveyoutbe`

Comment: and seems that program ran for while but coludn't import vlc module still now !

Comment: I tested this answer and worked for me. Remember that this solution is only for importing VLC. But it seems that you have errors on your code which mean it is a different problem.

Comment: but i have checked my code in my IDLE , it runs fine there without any error whereas the exe throws error. What could be possible reason ?

Comment: Thanks man!! Now it works fine , after adding the dll files i searched over web and found that i too needed to add the plugins folder of VLC and same you depicted in the answer , so instead of modifying the spec file , i did that with `--add-data` and finally code is on high . Again thanks for saving my time . I was totally confused

Comment: @MasoudRahimi Thank you so much for this answer. I mulled over past one week and finally, today your solution was exactly what I was needing for. But I still have one question, my exe file is now around 70MB in size due to the added VLC plugins, can I reduce it  somehow?

Comment: @Kartikeya If you have [upx](https://github.com/upx/upx) installed, PyInstaller would use it to compress the executable.

Comment: The fix of `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'media_player_new'` for onefile for windows is  `--add-data "./plugins/;./plugins/"` make sure that plugins is in the same path as main.py