# Pyinstaller cannot find libvlc.dll

Tags: python, dll, pyinstaller, libvlc

First, I know similar questions have been asked but I haven't been able to find a solution to my problem. Thank you for any help!

I have been trying to create an executable using pyinstaller, and I'm having trouble getting pyinstaller to find the .dlls for libvlc. In particular: libvlc.dll and libvlccore.dll. These are in my VideoLAN\VLC directory, but I also copied all the dlls from my VideoLAN\VLC directory to my Compile directory, next to my test.py and test.spec files. I also added my VideoLAN\VLC directory to my environment variables in an attempt to help pyinstaller find them. 
Despite this, when I run pyinstaller test.spec I get this warning:

```
48352 WARNING: lib not found: libvlccore.dll dependency of C:\Users\chipc\Desktop\Code\Python\KivyTest\KivyTut\Compile\libvlc.dll
```

The rest of the compile log can be seen here: https://pastebin.com/DJmkQ7nm

When trying to run the generated test.exe, it gives me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 149, in __init__
File "ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "c:\users\chipc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "site-packages\vlc.py", line 207, in <module>
File "site-packages\vlc.py", line 163, in find_lib
File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 151, in __init__
__main__.PyInstallerImportError: Failed to load dynlib/dll 'C:\\Users\\chipc\\Desktop\\Code\\Python\\KivyTest\\KivyTut\\Compile\\dist\\test\\libvlc.dll'. Most probably this dynlib/dll was not found when the application was frozen.
[16044] Failed to execute script test
```

In addition, the generated folder which includes test.exe does have libvlc.dll inside of it.

Here is my test.spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew
block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['test.py'],
             pathex=[('C:\\Users\\chipc\\Desktop\\Code\\Python\\KivyTest\\KivyTut\\Compile'), ('C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC')],
             binaries=[('./libvlc.dll', '.'), ('./axvlc.dll', '.'), ('./libvlccore.dll', '.'), ('./npvlc.dll', '.')],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
a.datas += Tree('C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\plugins', prefix='plugins')
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='test',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe, Tree('C:\\Users\\chipc\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\kivy_deps'),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='test')
```

The program works in PyCharm. How can I get pyinstaller to find libvlc.dll?

Just in case, here is is what my Compile directory looks like:

```
axvlc.dll
libvlc.dll
libvlccore.dll
npvlc.dll
test.py
test.spec
```

Thanks for any help, I've been trying to figure this out for a couple of days now!

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56919875/error-while-running-the-exe-file-made-with-pyinstaller/56924606#56924606) can help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I had seen that post already, and I have tried using the .spec formula posted there on a very small script that simply imports vlc and time, and prints something every 3 seconds. I still get a similar error: `__main__.PyInstallerImportError: Failed to load dynlib/dll 'C:\\Users\\chipc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI173322\\libvlc.dll'. Most probably this dynlib/dll was not found when the application was frozen.`

Comment: That error means it cannot find `libvlc.dll`. On runtime open the `_MEIXXXX` directory and check if the file is there or not.

Comment: It looks like it does create a libVLC.dll in the _MEIXXXX directory during runtime. The directory looks like this before it crashes: _bz2 _ctypes _hashlib _lzma _socket _ssl libcrypto-1_1.dll libssl-1_1.dll libVLC.dll libvlc.dylib libvlccore.dylib VCRUNTIME140.dll

Comment: It is strange because you have the DLLs in the directory. Have you tried running your script directly?

Comment: Yeah, running `python test.py` seems to work correctly. Also, it seems strange to me that I would get a warning that libvlc.dll has a dependency (libvlccore.dll) during compile--so, it _did_ find it during compile--but then not be able to find libvlc.dll when running the exe...

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem and i deleted vlc application and vlc module ,the problem was because vlc application was for 32bit and my pc 64 bit ,then installed the 64bit vlc application and after that downloaded the vlc module again and added the path of libvlc.dll to system variable ,everything gone well .........

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the stack posts WITH NO ANSWER that kept popping up in my Google searches.

Have you tried adding `libVLC.dll` to the binaries line like so:

```
a.binaries + [("libVLC.dll", "D:\KivySchool\VLC\libvlc.dll", "BINARY")],
```

I see this line `exclude_binaries=True,`, maybe delete it? I didn't have that line in my working specfile.

Example test.py

```
from sys import platform

if platform == "win32": #https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.platform
    import vlc
    import os
    import time

    vlc_player = vlc.MediaPlayer() 
    medianame = "bigbuckbunny x265.mp4"
    mediapath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), medianame)
    media = vlc.Media(mediapath)
    vlc_player.set_media(media)
    vlc_player.play()
    offset = 5
    time.sleep(offset)
    length = vlc_player.get_length() #time in ms (divide by 1000 to get in seconds)
    newoffset = length/1000 - offset
    time.sleep(newoffset)
```

Example specfile

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

medianame = "bigbuckbunny x265.mp4"

a = Analysis(
    ['basicpyvlc.py'],
    pathex=["D:\KivySchool\VLC"],
    binaries=[("D:\KivySchool\VLC\plugins\*", "plugins")],
    datas=[(medianame, ".")],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries + [("libVLC.dll", "D:\KivySchool\VLC\libvlc.dll", "BINARY")],
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='basicvlc',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
```

Works on: Win 10, x64 VLC, PyInstaller 6.3.0

repo here: https://github.com/AccelQuasarDragon/BasicPyVLC